# Is it possible to completely hide website's IP from everybody including the website's users?

Tags: security

There is a good article on how to protect your origin IP in https://blog.cloudflare.com/ddos-prevention-protecting-the-origin. All is good and clear on that page except when it comes to mail server, for which it says:

> **Don't host mail or other services on the same server as your web
>   server**
>
> If your mail server hosted by the same IP as your http server, an
>   attacker could find the IP address from an outgoing email. For
>   example, an attacker could send an email to a non-existent email
>   address on your server causing a bounce; the bounce might contain the
>   IP address of your server in its headers.

Ok, I know I can delegate mail to another server or such public services as Google Apps' mail. But then what about messages that originate from the website's scripts?! For example, if a user wants to register on your website then the confirmation messages has to go out from one of the website's script and that will reveal the IP address anyway, won't it?

The above article is probably good for simple static websites that do not send any messages to its visitors or registered users, however for every website that needs to communicate with the user base the problem of hiding the original IP is still there.

I would appreciate if experts could elaborate how to completely hide the server's IP for the website's that regularly send messages to its users.

Comment: "For example, if a user wants to register on your website then the confirmation messages has to go out from one of the website's script and that will reveal the IP address anyway, won't it?" No, not necessarily. Use a third-party for outgoing email like Sendgrid or Amazon SES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that it was possible to configure and use https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php#top_of_page So apparently it's possible to send all messages from the server from external IP.